# Representing summation $\frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{i=1}^{n} i(1+\frac{i}{n})^2$ as integral

Tags: real-analysis, summation, riemann-integration

Let $c_n = \frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{i=1}^{n} i(1+\frac{i}{n})^2$ and find $\lim_{n \to\infty} c_n$ if it exists.

My idea was to show that $\lim_{n \to\infty} c_n = $ integral of something that converges, but I'm having a hard time representing the summation as an integral due to the $1/n^3$. If that was instead $1/n^2$ then it would be equal to $\int_{0}^{1} x(x+1)^2 \,dx$ (we create a N partitions equally spaced on [0,1], then represent the summation as an upper Riemann sum of $x(x+1)^2$ ) But I'm not sure how to do it with $1/n^3.$

Comment: You're on the right track.  You've got $\frac1n$ times a Riemann sum.  The limit of a product is the product of the limits.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: $\lim_{n \to \infty} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n}(1+\frac{i}{n})^2 \frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} * \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n}(1+\frac{i}{n})^2 \frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} * \int_{0}^{1} x(x+1)^2 \, dx = 0 * \int_{0}^{1} x(x+1)^2 \, dx = 0.$

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.